# "No encode delegate" error with GraphicsMagick

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, graphicsmagick

I'm encountering an error during conversion of a PDF file to a PNG image.

The error is:

> Command failed: gm convert: No encode delegate for this image format (PNG) [No such file or directory].:

The code which opens the PDF and makes the image looks like:

```
gm((file_path + file_name))

    .size(async (err, size) => {

        if (!err) {

            if (size.width > options.width) {

                gm((file_path + file_name))

                    .resize(options.width)

                    .setFormat('png')

                    .autoOrient()

                    .noProfile()

                    .write((file_path + file_name_thumb), async (err) => {

                        if (!err) {

                            return resolve({
                                file_path,
                                file_name: file_name_thumb
                            });

                        } else {

                            await std.log('Error caught in image_advanced.thumb().', file_path, file_name, options, err);

                            return reject(err);

                        }

                    });

            } else {

                await fs.copyFileSync((file_path + file_name), (file_path + file_name_thumb));

                return resolve({
                    file_path,
                    file_name: file_name_thumb
                });

            }

        } else {

            await std.log('ERROR: No thumb returned in image_advanced.thumb().', file_path, file_name, options, err);

            return reject(err);

        }

    });
```

I believe I do have the delegates loaded and configured correctly.

When I run a configure on the instance, I see this output table:

[image]

This appears to indicate that PDF and PNG are supported/enabled.

This is an Amazon EC2 Linux 2 instance.

In reality, getting GraphicsMagick installed and configured was not easy so, like many others, I may have installed enabled more than one version and perhaps that's my issue?

Answer (score 0):

So, now it's all working without any code changes above.

If I had to hazard a very uneducated guess, it's b/c I ran another configure. It was the same as the last one b/c I used the up arrow in the shell:

./configure --with-png=yes --with-jpg=yes

Anyway, the code above CAN AND DOES convert all of the files I need (GIF, PNG, JPG, PDF) to PNG. For those of you pulling your hair out for a conversion solution, please try this code.

Oh and big props to the wizard behind the GM curtain who probably doesn't get near enough love: Bob Friesenhahn!